# 14.04 How can I adapt my screen to the lower resolution of a undetected projector (nvidia driver)?

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, projector

I am trying to connect projector on my laptop with a VGA - mini display port adapter. I use an Nvidia card with nvidia-352 driver. The projector is not automatically recognized , but i can get a display on the projector by typing the command :

```
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 1024x768
```

1024x768 is the native resolution of the projector, and 1920x1080 is the resolution of my screen. The projector will only show partly my screen (i.e. only the 1024x768 top-left pixels).

However if I use :

```
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 1920x1080
```

it shows the whole screen, but the projector display is unreadable.

nvidia-settings does not detect the projector, I can't use it to change the projector resolution or to use twin view.

Is there any way to display two different resolutions of the same screen (one on the projector, one on my laptop) ?